# How to find out which driver files belong to a certain hardware device like a printer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, kernel, drivers

On a certain machine I installed a Dell 2355dn Laser MFP printer, now how can I find out what files on the hard drive are used as drivers to access the printer.

I assume they must be under c:\windows\system32\drivers, right?

I know DriverView from NirSoft that lists all drivers on the system, but I did not find any Dell drivers?

Any ideas how to list them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see all file associated with Specific Driver in `Driver File Details`

- Open Device Manager window ( Go to RUN menu and type "devmgmt.msc")

[image: Device manager Window]

- rigght Click on  particular Device that you want and select Properties
  [image: Go To Properties Of Device]
- in Properties window Click on Driver Details button
  [image: Driver Details]

  - in Driver Details Window You can see What files are associated with this Device Driver
    [image: associated files with Device Driver]

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

In my case the drivers for one of my **network** printers were located in system32\spool.

To find out, I opened the printer porperties in DeviceManager/PrintQueues/[14]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If the thing is configured in Device Manager, then you can find which driver is being used on one of the tabs of its properties.